# Django 400 Bad request after pulling update from Github

Tags: python, django, github, http-status-code-400, django-channels

I had a working page running Django with channels via Nginx, Daphne, Redis, and Gunicorn. After pulling an update from Github my index page now shows "Bad Request (400)" with nothing helpful in the console except for missing favicon. My settings.py has DEBUG = False and ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['AWS_IP']. Can anyone help me figure out what might be causing this?

Comment: To be clear, are you getting this error when running locally or on your server?

Comment: I am running on my server. Also, after clearing cookies my error has changed to 
 server error (500)

Comment: Nothing helpful in the console for the 500 error?

Comment: Only thing in the console is that favicon was not found 404

Comment: Also I am now noticing on my local machine that if I set DEBUG = False I start to get 404 errors for my static files. I do not believe it is related as Ngnix handles the static files on the server (and I don't have Nginx to handle it locally).

Comment: Perhaps this is related to your allowed hosts? You can try to set it to [*] to allow any host, which should tell you whether this is causing the problem or if it's unrelated.

Comment: I am now having problems on my local computer that I was not having earlier. I think I will just nuke this update and try again.

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear that. Best of luck!